# ¿Que error ocurre en el .htacess en ubuntu?

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu-server

Tengo el siguiente `.htaccess` en mi servidor local (*windows, xampp*) funcionando correctamente:

```
DirectoryIndex cargador_contenido.php

RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule ^home?$ paginas/pagina1.php
RewriteRule ^mobile?$ paginas/pagina1m.php
RewriteRule ^espera-m?$ paginas/pagina2m.php
RewriteRule ^espera?$ paginas/pagina2.php
RewriteRule ^email$ paginas/pagina3.php
RewriteRule ^email-m$ paginas/pagina3m.php
RewriteRule ^personal?$ paginas/pagina4.php
RewriteRule ^personal-m?$ paginas/pagina4m.php
RewriteRule ^final?$ paginas/pagina12.php



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Cuando lo subo a mi vps con unbuntu entra en conflicto mostrando error404

Comment: Mira el registro de errores (suele ser error.log) de apache/php porque ahí estará justo el error concreto que necesitas resolver.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: `sudo a2enmod rewrite` activa el modulo de rewrites, luego en el .conf del virtual server en la section `<Directory /var/www>` le agregas `AllowOverride All` o [`AllowOverride FileInfo`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/overrides.html#override-fileinfo) para activar los `.htaccess` . `sudo service apache2 restart` y debería salir andando